# Tkinter window not responding after Text Insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm new to Python and just started venturing into doing GUIs. I created a Tkinter window that is pretty basic: it has 3 Entry bars and 3 File Dialog buttons. When you chose the 3rd directory, the GUI file automatically makes a call to a separate file and receives a large text block which is then displayed in a Text box.

The whole thing works correctly, but my problem is that after receiving and inserting the text response, Tkinter stops working and doesn't allow the user to scroll down.

I read that one reason this happens is because people use both `.pack( )` and `.grid( )`, but I'm not mixing those two functions.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my GUI file

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from gui_GPSExtractor import *
import os


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize Frame """
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid( )
        self.startGUI( )

    """ Create Labels, Text Boxes, File Dialogs, and Buttons """
    def startGUI(self):
        # Label for Scan Path
        self.dLabel = Label(self, text = "Scan Path")
        self.dLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        # Entry for Scan Path
        self.dEntry = Entry(self, width = 60)
        self.dEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # Button for Scan Path Directory Browse
        self.dButton = Button(self, text = "Browse", command = lambda: self.browseFiles("d"))
        self.dButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # Label for CSV Path
        self.cLabel = Label(self, text = "CSV Path")
        self.cLabel.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        # Entry for CSV Path
        self.cEntry = Entry(self, width = 60)
        self.cEntry.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # Button for CSV Path Directory Browse
        self.cButton = Button(self, text = "Browse", command = lambda: self.browseFiles("c"))
        self.cButton.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # Label for Log Path
        self.lLabel = Label(self, text = "Log Path")
        self.lLabel.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        # Entry for Log Path
        self.lEntry = Entry(self, width = 60)
        self.lEntry.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # Button for Log Path Directory Browse
        self.lButton = Button(self, text = "Browse", command = lambda: self.browseFiles("l"))
        self.lButton.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # Text Box for Results
        self.resultText = Text(self, width = 60, height = 30, wrap = WORD, borderwidth = 3, relief = SUNKEN)
        self.resultText.grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

        # Scrollbar for Text Box
        self.scrollBar = Scrollbar(self, command = self.resultText.yview)
        self.scrollBar.grid(row = 9, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")
        self.resultText["yscrollcommand"] = self.scrollBar.set

    def browseFiles(self, btnCalling):
        if(btnCalling == "d"):
            self.dName = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/python3-CH05")
            self.dEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.dEntry.insert(0, self.dName)
        elif(btnCalling == "c"):
            self.cName = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/python3-CH05")
            self.cEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.cEntry.insert(0, self.cName)
        elif(btnCalling == "l"):
            self.lName = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = "/python3-CH05")
            self.lEntry.delete(0, END)
            self.lEntry.insert(0, self.lName)
            output = extractGPS(self.dName, self.cName, self.lName)
            self.resultText.delete(0.0, END)
            self.resultText.insert(0.0, output)

# Start the GUI
root = Tk( )
root.title("Python gpsExtractor")
root.geometry("650x650")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop( )
```

Comment: The task that `extractGPS` performs is time-consuming?

Comment: @eyllanesc The short answer is no. I'm running tests on a small set of data. `extractGPS` is searching a small directory containing 10 JPEG files and collecting EXIF metadata from each file. The `output` text is also printed to the Terminal and that happens immediately

Comment: You could test the code without that task and verify that it generates the same error.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to insert into text widget? I just replaced your `extractGPS` with common list and raw string and it works well. Can you confirm that code execution returns to `mainloop` from `extractGPS`?

Comment: FWIW, `0.0` is not a correct index. Text widget indexes are strings of the form <line>.<character>, with line numbers starting at one. Thus, the very first character is `"1.0"`.

Comment: @CommonSense How can I tell if my code execution returns to `mainloop` ? I have a return statement in the function `extractGPS`, but do I have to do something extra to make sure it returns to `mainloop`? 
@BryanOakley Thanks for the heads up, I'll adjust that in the code

Comment: @wmarquez, You can place a break point (depends on IDE you using, if there's one) right before `return` to see where code flow goes after that. In general, your problem (unresponsible gui) occures when flow stuck anywhere outside `mainloop`. It can be because of a time-consuming procedure (like @eyllanesc mentioned) or a bug (overlapping event's callbacks, inf loops and more nasty things). As I mentioned before - code works well w/o `extractGPS` for me, so I think that the problem lays behind this function, hence, if you really stuck - you need to update your question with `extractGPS` code!